# text-rotate property not working in email body of PHP

Tags: php, css, email, html-email

I have an email body in which I have set `text-transform` to rotation. The problem is when the email is sent to the inbox from a PHP website, the text is not rotated, and plain text is shown instead. Here is my email body code:

```
// Birthday wish email body parameters
$name = "website Support";
$email = "website@website.com";
$rec = website@website.com;
$sub = "Happy Birthday !";
$body = '<div style="width:150px; margin-left:200px; margin-top:280px; color:#FE923C;font-size:20px; transform:rotate(8deg);-ms-transform:rotate(8deg);-moz-transform:rotate(8deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(8deg);-o-transform:rotate(8deg);"><b>First Name</b></div>';
$header='Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
$header .= "From: $name < ". $email ." >";
mail($rec,$sub,$body,$header);
```

Comment: What browser? What email program (if any)? We need more details.

Comment: Have you set in the email headers "Content-type: text/html;" ?

Comment: no email client that i know of supports this, email client html support is generally poor. you need to tick to more basic markup.

Comment: I am using chrome and firefox browsers. I am sending email through website by php script.

Comment: This email has a problem with showing background. In yahoo, correct email is sent, but gmail and hotmail not receiving correct emails. In gmail, styling is missing and hotmail is not receiving background.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two minor mistakes:

```
$rec = "website@website.com";
$header .= "From: $name < ". $email ." >\r\n";
```

The html you provided does work in my browser.

Your right its not rotated when editing or viewing the HTML in outlook 2003 which I'm using. Perhaps outlook 2003 was too early a version of email client to support the translation.

Outlook 2003 by default uses microsoft word to EDIT its html - if I untick this option in options then I can't seem to be able to edit the HTML anymore, the "HTML Source" option under View (you can add to the toolbar using Customize) disappears, but this doesn't matter. I've heard that outlook 2003 renders html using internet explorer when viewing emails, however I can confirm that the text was not rotated when I viewed an email I sent to myself using MS-Word editor in outlook to edit the HTML source. I suspect it's probably using word to view the HTML in the email maybe this was a patch/update for office 2003.

Outlook 2007/2010 uses microsoft word (part of microsoft office) to render its HTML.

If you look at this link:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx#Word2007MailHTMLandCSS_Introduction
```

you will see that word 2007 does not list the "transform" css property as a supported property.

Have a look also at http://www.fixoutlook.org/

As you can see from that site there are people who want outlook to support the full set of HTML/CSS.

What you could do is to have a link in the email that the user can click, when they click the link it can open in the browser and the rotation should work there.

Another possibility is to have an .html file as an attachment. When I receive an .html attachment in outlook 2003, if I double click on it, it opens in firefox browser.

However there's always the possibility that an .html attachment might open in the outlook word viewer, in outlook 2010/2007, you'd have to try it. Even a link could open in the word viewer, potentially - though hopefully not.

Answer (score 0):

Many email clients/services don't support the CSS transform property - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/